# What is the opposite of rest/remainder?

Tags: antonyms

I'm searching for a noun that represents the opposite of rest/remainder.

For example, "Highlight the rest of this page." The word "rest" in this case represents everything between the current location and the end of the page.

I'm looking for a word that would represent everything between the current location and the beginning of the page.

Comment: dividend, quotient, remainder. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_quotient. Instead of left-right, if you place a dividing cursor at a page, the fore-quotient, the rear quotient.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> "Highlight **{the foregoing text / the text above / the preceding text / the preceding part of the page}".**